# Understanding the logic behind clear() in ArrayList

Tags: java

I am using below program to find the subsequences in an given given list. When I am using `clear()` , the values in `li` is also getting cleared. Hence, I am creating a new reference everytime.

I wanted to understand the logic behind this. Am I using it wrong? Or it is the reference that I am adding to my `li`?

```
 public static int getTheSubseq(List<Integer> AList){
      //  int[][] subsequences = new int[][];
      List<List<Integer>> li = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int i = 0; i < AList.size(); i++){
          for(int j =i+1; j < AList.size(); j++){
              temp.add(AList.get(i));
              temp.add(AList.get(j));
              li.add(temp);
              temp = new ArrayList<>();
              //temp.clear();
          }
      }
      System.out.println(li);
      return 1;

    }
```

Comment: Adding the element to `li` doesn't make a copy. You may want to just declare `temp` inside the inner loop, so you get a fresh one every time.

Comment: Question: how many different `ArrayList`s do you want `li` to contain after the loop? If you used `.clear()` instead of `new ArrayList()` inside the loop, how many times would `new ArrayList()` be executed in that method? Are those two numbers the same?

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether or not you are calling `temp.clear()`, if you add to `li` multiple times a reference to the same `List` object, `li` will contain multiple references to the same `List` object, which means `li.get(0) == li.get(1)`, `li.get(0) == li.get(2)`, and so on...

Making changes in one of these inner `List`s will be reflected in all the other inner `List`s, since there's just one `List` referenced multiple times.

Therefore, assigning a new `ArrayList` instance to `temp` in each iteration of your loop (before adding it to `li`) is the right thing to do.

I'd make a slight change though - create the new inner `List` just before adding it to the outer `List`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AList.size(); i++){
    for(int j =i+1; j < AList.size(); j++){
        List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp.add(AList.get(i));
        temp.add(AList.get(j));
        li.add(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assigning a new instance and creating a new arrayList. It seems kind of the same thing. Why do you say create a new list?

Comment: @user1896796 an ArrayList is an implementation of the List interface, so when I'm saying create a new List, I mean the creation of the new ArrayList in your specific example.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the element to `li` doesn't make a copy. So when you call `clear()` you'll have both `temp` and an element inside `li` that point to the same object.

You may want to just declare `temp` inside the inner loop, so you get a fresh one every time without needing to call `clear()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `.clear()` (or any other method for that matter), you're operating on the **same refernece**.
Here, if you don't create a new list each iteration, you're adding the list referenced to by `temp` to `li`. When you call `clear()`, they are "all" cleared, since they all point to the same object. 
When you create a new list each iteration, you have **different** objects, and can operate on them independently.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
public static int getTheSubseq(List<Integer> AList){
  //  int[][] subsequences = new int[][];
  List<List<Integer>> li = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Integer> temp;

  for (int i = 0; i < AList.size(); i++){
      for(int j =i+1; j < AList.size(); j++){
          temp = new ArrayList<>();
          temp.add(AList.get(i));
          temp.add(AList.get(j));
          li.add(temp);
      }
  }
  System.out.println(li);
  return 1;

}
```